# Set file to be opened automatically when opening a C# solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I changed the name of my folder which holds my project. Now when i open the project in Visual Studio, no files open automatically. It is important that i submit this project very professionally. Is there a way that i can make my Form.cs file show automatically in VS when the project is opened, as it does by default if you do not change the project folder name?

Comment: When you open a project Visual Studio automatically loads all your opened files in your previous session. Do you absolutely need to close all previously opened files and open a specific file? I think this is wrong because what happens if Form.cs doesn't exist in the project you try to load?

Comment: You cannot work.  The state of the windows in your solution is preserved in a hidden .suo file.  It can only work on your machine, not another one.  Writing an add-on to go along with your project would be a solution but is complete overkill.

Comment: @HansPassant I now see that if i close VS with the file loaded, it is there when i open VS again. So when any project is loaded onto a new machine for the first time, will it default to not opening any files? I have no issues then.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to right click on the project in Solution Explorer, go to:

> Add -> Existing Item

Then find your Form.cs file

Comment: he changed the name of the project folder and lost associated files for the project